# Automated localized screenshots

Tags: android, windows, automation, localization, screenshot

Is there a way to automate taking localized screenshots on android from windows?

I found a tool for Mac

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/screenshots/

But is there a way to do it on Windows? I need to take 5 screenshots for 11 different languages, it would be nice to automate it somehow.

**EDIT**

Following [this post](https://dev.to/serhuz/capturing-screenshots-on-android-with-espresso-and-junit-81f) from the @grrrrrr answer I have made automation to capture my **FirstActivity** with all localizations. However, I can't find out how to go through my app and get screenshots from several activities, change localization and go through them again. Flow should be like this:

'en'
FirstActivity(scr) > MainActivity(scr) > SettingsActivity(scr)...

'de'
FirstActivity(scr) > MainActivity(scr) > SettingsActivity(scr)...

and so on.

**EDIT 2**

Atm I am doing this by manually changing activities in

```
private final CustomActivityTestRule mActivityTestRule = new CustomActivityTestRule<>(StartActivity.class);
```

and doing screenshots one by one.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://dev.to/serhuz/capturing-screenshots-on-android-with-espresso-and-junit-81f) is a great guide on how to take screenshots of your automated tests when they fail or succeed (almost your exact use case of localization too!). You could follow the guide to create a `ScreenshotWatcher` or simply call the `captureScreenshot` method as needed to get the screenshots you need. I have copied the relevant class below:

```
public class ScreenshotWatcher extends TestWatcher {

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        Locale locale = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
                .getResources()
                .getConfiguration()
                .getLocales()
                .get(0);
        captureScreenshot(description.getMethodName() + "_" + locale.toLanguageTag());
    }


    private void captureScreenshot(String name) {
        ScreenCapture capture = Screenshot.capture();
        capture.setFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG);
        capture.setName(name);
        try {
            capture.process();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        captureScreenshot(description.getMethodName() + "_fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see it is a nice walkthrough, but not everything is explained. Is there a link maybe to the whole project?

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? Are you not already using Espresso to automate your tests? Here is a walkthrough on how to get started with that https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/

Comment: This is my first time using Espresso. Is there a way to edit this automation and set "path" to take screenshots of several activities and then change localization. For example "MainActivity (screenshot) > FirstActivity (screenshot) > ThirdActivity (screenshot)"

Comment: You can navigate to the other activities inside of `emptyMainActivityPortrait` or you could create another `@Test` for a different activity or you could subclass `MainActivityScreenshot` and pass in the different actiivies you want to test

Comment: Yes, I did change activities and manually do the screenshots one by one. Just asking if it can be automated. Not working if I go to other activity from `emptyMainActivityPortrait`

Comment: You'd need to call `captureScreenshot` manually after navigating -- the linked solution is clean as it abstracts the capturing. Your best bet is probably to subclass `MainActivityScreenshot`

Comment: How can I subclass and pass it?